# Using a variable in brace expansion range fed to a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, brace-expansion

Here is myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..$1};
do
    echo $1 $i;
done
```

If I run `myscript.sh 3` the output is

```
3 {1..3}
```

instead of

```
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

Clearly `$3` contains the right value, so why doesn't `for i in {1..$1}` behave the same as if I had written `for i in {1..3}` directly?

Comment: Your example script will work in both ksh93 and zsh.

Comment: Minor thing: You wrote $3 ("Clearly $3 contains ...") but are using $1 in your script. Why not just remove the $1? It doesn't have that much relevance except to prove that variable expansion works.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should use a C-style for loop to accomplish this:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do
   echo $i
done
```

This avoids external commands and nasty eval statements.

Comment: Not working for me
`test.sh: line 1: ((: i<=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<=")`

Comment: @Temak are you using `bash`? Is your shebang `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: @jordann, file contains only these 3 lines. 
I'm using GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).
I run script `bash test.sh`

Comment: @Temak you need to run it like this: `bash test.sh 12`. The `$1` is a positional arg.

Comment: Yes, I haven't noticed. Sorrry:)

Answer (score 27):

Because brace expansion occurs before expansion of variables. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion.

If you want to use braces, you could so something grim like this:

```
for i in `eval echo {1..$1}`;
do
    echo $1 $i;
done
```

Summary: Bash is vile.

Comment: Heh, +1 for the answer, -0.5 for the vile.

Comment: @glennjackman: Wow, you're saying that Bash's myriad expansion and escaping rules aren't vile?

Comment: I feel dirty for saying +1 on an answer involving `eval`. Re: vile: `bash` isn't vile, but it's a bit like drinking grain alcohol straight. Some people seem to like it but it's hard not to choke at first and the more you do it the less you're bothered by it.

Comment: @Sorpigal: It must just be me then.  I use it pretty much every day, and it still bothers me... (but then I'm not good with straight alchohol either)

Comment: This is yet working and solving the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

You can use `seq` command:

```
for i in `seq 1 $1`
```

Or you can use the C-style `for...loop`:

```
for((i=1;i<=$1;i++))
```

Comment: A C-style for loop is preferred over the external seq command.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to expand variables inside braces **without eval**:

```
end=3
declare -a 'range=({'"1..$end"'})'
```

We now have a nice array of numbers:

```
for i in ${range[@]};do echo $i;done
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've mentioned bash in the heading, but I would add that 'for i in {$1..$2}' works as intended in zsh. If your system has zsh installed, you can just change your shebang to zsh.

Using zsh with the example 'for i in {$1..$2}' also has the added benefit that $1 can be less than $2 and it still works, something that would require quite a bit of messing about if you wanted that kind of flexibility with a C-style for loop.