# De-referencing variables in a bash/ksh script in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, ksh

Suppose I do the following:

```
$ echo {10..20}
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$ A=10
$ B=20
$ echo {${A}..${B}}
{10..20}
```

Why does this not expand as it did the first time?

I am trying to set up a "for" loop in a script:

```
for i in {10..20}
do
    echo ${i}
done
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

But if I use variables...

```
for i in {${A}..${B}}
do
    echo ${i}
done
{10..20}
```

I tried using "eval". Didn't work.

```
for i in `eval {${A}..${B}}`
...
```

I tried parentheses. Didn't work.

```
for i in "{${A}..${B}}"
...
```

What else can I try, other than

```
seq ${A} ${B}
```

?

Comment: You could use brace expansion with `eval` like this `for i in $(eval echo {$A..$B})`, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Related: [Using a variable in brace expansion range fed to a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9911056/6862601).

Comment: `ksh` doesn't *have* range expansion but some of the solutions in the duplicate work for `ksh` too, as well as of course the `for` loop `for((i=A;i<=B;++i))`

Answer (score 2):

It does not expand by definition. Taken from the bash manual:

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are
>   either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment,
>   is an integer.

And

> Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It
>   is strictly textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation
>   to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces.

So you must provide integers or characters, and the interpretation is textual, no interpretation of the text between the braces.

I think you have no other option besides using `seq` or another approach like a loop where you take care of incrementing a variable from start to end.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for ((i=A; i<=B; i++)) ; do
    echo $i
done
```