# paste a list of files in a range in bash

Tags: bash, sequence, paste

I have a list of files named "LL1.txt" to "LL1180.txt" but I am only interested in files from 1 to 50 to paste them in one file.
I tried using:

```
seq 1 50
for n in $(seq $1 $2); do 
    f="LL$n.txt"
    if [ -e $f ]; then
        paste "$f" > LL$1_$2.txt
    fi
done
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Please show two files and your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for n in `seq $start $stop` ; do
if [ -e "$LL$n.txt" ] ; then   
cat LL$n.txt >> output_file  
fi
done
```

or if you enjoy harder way:

```
cat > output_file <<< `cat  LL{1..50}.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give all the filenames as arguments to `paste` so it will combine them.

```
paste FILE{1..50}.txt > LL1_50.txt
```

Note that you can't use variables in the braced range. See [Using a variable in brace expansion range fed to a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911056/using-a-variable-in-brace-expansion-range-fed-to-a-for-loop) if you need workarounds.